# Hydration of a VUE prerendered page

Tags: vue.js, prerender

I'm have a prerendered page using [prerender spa plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) at build time. When VUE kicks in, it  destroys the DOM (more specifically application root div) and the apps components are rendered as usual.

I would like to know if it is possible to wake up VUE in such way that it doesn't destroy the DOM when mounting.

Note: adding [data-server-rendered](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html) on the prerendered elements or mounting the app with the `true` hydratation flag did not worked.

Comment: @tao I'm trying to preserve the dom elements, not an event. From the documentation: VUE "know that the markup is rendered by the server and it should mount in hydration mode". I though that means that for something like
`<div id="app" data-server-redendered="true">`
   `<p class="super-text"> ... </p>`
`</div>`
VUE checks the innnerHtml of the app.div and inner p, and instead of removing them from the DOM, updates the innnerHTML. But it doesn't. Instead removes ("destroys") the div.app and reconstructs the markup.

Comment: Which is what I would like to prevent.

Comment: According to [docs](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html) this shouldn't happen. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: This may be your case: "In development mode, Vue will assert the client-side generated virtual DOM tree matches the DOM structure rendered from the server. If there is a mismatch, it will bail hydration, discard existing DOM and render from scratch." >  Quoted from [Quasar's documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-ssr/client-side-hydration).